# Problem with move files from root folder to subfolder on hosting

Tags: php

I would like to ask you bout this problem. I tried to clean some files on hosting little bit and I put login files (login, registter,...) to subfolder auth.

But when I try to load webpage auth/login.php it shows me error 500.

I remove this part of code from login.php and page was loaded.

```
require_once "_inc/DBController.php";
require_once "_inc/Auth.php";
require_once "_inc/Util.php";

$auth = new Auth();
$db_handle = new DBController();
$util = new Util();

// if form was not sent then check if user is logged in
require_once "_inc/ValidateCookiesSessionLogin.php";
```

Can you advise me what can be problem?

My folders structure is:

```
www_root/_inc/config_files.php
www_root/auth/login_files.php
www_root/index_and_other_files.php
```

Here is my error log:

```
[Tue Nov 23 02:00:02 2021] [error] [client 93.184.77.22] PHP Warning:  require_once(_inc/Auth.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/gm016900/www_root/auth/new-login.php on line 3
[Tue Nov 23 02:00:02 2021] [error] [client 93.184.77.22] PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '_inc/Auth.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear/') in /home/gm016900/www_root/auth/new-login.php on line 3
```

Thank you

Comment: If you get a generic 500 error, the first step is to check your PHP error log file to find the underlying error message.

Comment: Well that seems pretty straightforward don't you think? Go and check what file it's trying to open on line 3, and check that the file being mentioned (`_inc/Auth.php`) exists and is in the correct folder. Presumably, it doesn't - hence the error.

Comment: I checked it, but this file exists. Also if I transfer new-login.php back to root folder it is working well. File is on server and it has exactly same name and it is in folder_inc. If I remove 'require_once "_inc/Auth.php"' I get the same error for Util.php. Maybe I need some another way how to write path to this files when I call this php files from another subfolder.

Comment: Ok well maybe the relative path is wrong then. If login.php is under `/auth` then `_inc` is not a subfolder of that. You need to go up a level first. So maybe should be `require_once "../_inc/Auth.php";`. But I'm surprised it doesn't also fall over on the previous and subsequent lines in that case. Are there any other errors in the log as well?

Comment: So I tried it and check logs again and it get another error `PHP Warning:  require_once(_inc/Auth.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/gm016900/www_root/_inc/ValidateCookiesSessionLogin.php on line 2` I will check it and let you know. It seems that I will find solution oin near time. Thanks for good advice to check logs.

Comment: Remember, the path you're specifying for the `require` must be relative to the current script, not the site root.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Now, I have clear in it. A lot of helps me to check error logs, bcz I already used ../ but I had the same error and I think it did not help. But there were 2nd problem with path also in another validate.php file which are connected together. I needed to change `require_once "_inc/Auth.php";` to `require_once "Auth.php";`  Now problem is solved.